# How did Gods select their animal vehicles?

Tags: gods, animals, vahana

For example,

[image: Ganesha]

Ganesh --> Mouse

Durga --> Lion

Shiva -–> Bull, and the list is endless....

So, how are these assigned or rather selected by all the Gods as their vehicles?

**OR**

Is it just that we humans related the qualities of these animals to the Gods?

Comment: This regards to the Guna they were given lordship this are symbol which convey msg on what they do such a big god resting on small mouse means ganapthu lord indriya that is mouse here from this image one should understanding function if want control sex urges pray ganapathy

Comment: Devourer of enemy if some goes for war worship durga and fight like lion

Comment: Bull is symbol death if some wants escape untimely demis pray  siva

Comment: What is seleted?

Comment: @PrasannaR That looks like an answer. You should consider writing an answer.

Comment: It must be select misspelled @Wikash_

Comment: Bull is not the symbol of death. It is the symbol of Dharma. Buffalo is the symbol of death. @PrasannaR

Comment: @SeverusSnape yes may be it answer the question, but the site works like this.. its not like what you know you give answer on should refere exact scripture for the statement you made in the answer from scripture.. otherwise you statement are mere your statement its not hindu statement.its deleted..And i can give sloka for Ganapathy and Shiva..but im missing for Durga.. so left..

Comment: Who is dharma raja-> Yama->who have his lord as shiva.. Bull->Dharma->Yama->Shiva.. so utimately lord of death or annhilation is Shiva.. .@Rickross

Comment: Lord Shiva is Yamantaka (one who kills death); so Yama can't have Shiva as Ishta. As per Agni Purana, Yama is a devotee of Lord Vishnu. @PrasannaR